# Set a number value limit in SQL

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL, and I have a table group with a group_cap column. How do I specify in SQL that column group_cap cannot be a value greater than 4. For example, there cannot be more than 4 people in group A.

Comment: What database system are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a constraint on the table.

```
ALTER TABLE [group] ADD CONSTRAINT
    CK_group_cap CHECK (group_cap <= 4)
```

for a range of values, use `between`

```
ALTER TABLE [group] ADD CONSTRAINT
    CK_group_cap CHECK (group_cap between 1 and 4)
```

Comment: What if I want a minimum value of 1 along with the maximum value of 4?

Comment: @user1207457 you can use a `between` expression to check for a range

Comment: The characters `[`a nd `]` are invalid in SQL (they are legal in SQL Server though). For a standard SQL constraint, double quotes `"` have to be used to quote reserved words.

Comment: @jhinkley would (group_cap <= 4 and group_cap >= 1) be legal? I didn't seem to get any errors running that...

Comment: @user1207457 yes...that will get you the same results as the between statement.  It's also more clear that the end points are inclusive when you write it that way.